# Remove trailing whitespace at the end of aspx file

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to remove trailing whitespace including `\r` and `\n` at the end of aspx files by using Find and Replace using the pattern

```
\s+(?!.)
```

trying to replace whitespace followed by nothing with nothing.

The result is that everything will come on the same line.

Why?

I also tried `\s+$` with the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a negative lookahead to the end of your current pattern:

```
(\s+\r?\n)+$(?!.)
```

This will ensure that only final lines with whitespace only are matched.  See the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/giR3hR/1).

Comment: Ah, so `$` can be followed by stuff then!

Comment: `\s+$(?![\r\n.])` was also successful

Comment: @AndersLindén Yes, putting a lookahead after `$` is a bit unusual, but this is one instance where it is justified.